# Count the number of zeros with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'State': ['EU','EU','EU','US','US','US','UK','UK','UK'],
    'Var': [4,1,6,2,1,6,2,0,1],
    'Mark': [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
}

Table = pd.DataFrame(data)
Table
```

I want to count the number of zeros in the `"Mark"` column for each country. the output should be a table like this:

```
State  #ofZeros
EU       1
US       2
UK       3
```

I managed to count the number of "1s" in the `"Mark"` column for each country with `groupby`:

```
Table.groupby('State')['Mark'].sum()
```

and it would be great to know if it is possible to count also the zeros (or anyother value) with `groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

Group the dataframe by `States` then call `sum` on boolean masking for `Mark==0`.

```py
>>> Table.groupby('State', sort=False)['Mark'].agg(lambda x:x.eq(0).sum())

State
EU    1
US    2
UK    3
Name: Mark, dtype: int64
```

You can also call `to_frame` to convert it to a dataframe, then reset the index if needed:

```py
Table.groupby('State', sort=False)['Mark'].agg(lambda x:x.eq(0).sum()).to_frame('#of Zeros').reset_index()

  State  #of Zeros
0    EU          1
1    US          2
2    UK          3
```

**On a side note**, as you have mentioned in the question: *I managed to count the number of "1s" in the "Mark" column for each country with groupby: `Table.groupby('State')['Mark'].sum()`*,

No, you are not actually counting the number of 1s, you are just getting the `sum` of the values in `Mark` column for each groups. For the sample data you have, `Mark` column has only 0 and 1 values, that is why `sum` and count of 1s, both are equal. If it had some other values as well in addition to 0, and 1, the `sum` of the values would be different than the count of 1s.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually check the occurrences of value 0 in the column "Mark" using the code below.

```py
Table[['State', 'Mark']][Table.Mark == 0].value_counts()
```

`Table[['State', 'Mark']]` narrows the columns that are required to be shown.

The output should be

```
State  Mark
UK     0       3
US     0       2
EU     0       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This does not return the count per State

Comment: Please check the edited code that reflects what is required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `value_counts` when you filter the dataframe on state. Then you just lookup the count of value `0`.

```
states = set(Table.State)
count_data = [[state, Table[Table.State == state].Mark.value_counts()[0]] for state in states]
df = pd.DataFrame(count_data, columns=['State', 'zeros'])
df
print(df)
>> 
    State   zeros
0   US      2
1   UK      3
2   EU      1
```